# PHP readfile() causing corrupt file downloads

Tags: php, file-io, download

I am using php script to provide download from my website after a requisite javascript timer this php script is included which causes the download. But the downloaded file is corrupt no matter whatever I try. Can anyone help me point out where am I going wrong.

This is my code

```
     <?php
include "db.php";    
 $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
 $error = false;
    $conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!($conn)) echo "Failed To Connect To The Database!";
    else{   
        if(mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$conn)){
            $qry = "SELECT Link FROM downloads WHERE ID=$id";
            try{
                $result = mysql_query($qry);
                if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1){
                    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        $f=$rows['Link'];
                    }
                    //pathinfo returns an array of information
                    $path = pathinfo($f);
                    //basename say the filename+extension
                    $n = $path['basename'];
                    //NOW comes the action, this statement would say that WHATEVER output given by the script is given in form of an octet-stream, or else to make it easy an application or downloadable
                    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
                    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($f));
                    //This would be the one to rename the file
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$n.'');
                    //Finally it reads the file and prepare the output
                    readfile($f);
                    exit();
                }else $error = true;
            }catch(Exception $e){
                $error = true;
            }
            if($error) 
            {
                header("Status: 404 Not Found");
                }
        }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Do you have them 5 spaces before the start of `<?php`? Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: Remove any space before the starting php tag, start the script with `ob_start`, and do `ob_clean` before `readfile`.

Comment: I am learning PDO...thanks for the advice. By the way this script is running on 000webhost which is not likely to change the PHP version so soon for the free webhosting offer...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, as some people pointed out on the comments, remove all spaces before the opening PHP tag (`<?php`) on the first line and that should do the trick (unless this file is included or required by some other file).

When you print anything on the screen, even a single space, your server will send the headers along with the content to be printed (in the case, your blank spaces). To prevent this from happening, you can:

a) not print anything before you're done writing the headers;

b) run an ob_start() as the first thing in your script, write stuff, edit your headers and then ob_flush() and ob_clean() whenever you want your content to be sent to the user's browser.

In b), even if you successfully write your headers without getting an error, the **spaces will corrupt your binary file**. You should only be writing your binary content, not a few spaces with the binary content.

The **ob_** prefix stands for Output Buffer. When calling `ob_start()`, you tell your application that everything you output (`echo`, `printf`, etc) should be held in memory until you explicitly tell it to 'go' (`ob_flush()`) to the client. That way, you hold the output along with the headers, and when you are done writing them, they will be sent just fine along with the content.

Comment: It was because of space before the php tag... banged my head so much but could not locate it myself... Thank You so much...for the timely help...

Comment: Also, if you're having this issue make sure you are `flush()`ing the output buffer like in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) .

Comment: I have been looking for such an answer for days... Thank you very much, you saved me so much time!

Answer (score 29):

This helped me in case of more output buffers was opened.

```
//NOW comes the action, this statement would say that WHATEVER output given by the script is given in form of an octet-stream, or else to make it easy an application or downloadable
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($f));
//This would be the one to rename the file
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$n.'');
//clean all levels of output buffering
while (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
readfile($f);
exit();
```

Comment: That 'while' was the fix to my problem: a couple of bytes missing after the download. I don't know how they are related but that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 5):

```
           ob_start();//add this to the beginning of your code 

      if (file_exists($filepath) && is_readable($filepath) ) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$files");
 header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
   header('Pragma: public');
 header("content-length=".filesize($filepath));
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

   /*add while (ob_get_level()) {
       ob_end_clean();
         }  before readfile()*/
  while (ob_get_level()) {
ob_end_clean();
   }
    flush();
   readfile($filepath);
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer - even if this is a very old question.
Would be great if you could add some more info around the code snippet to help anyone who finds this answer understand what you are suggesting and why.

Comment: It's been years and this solved my issue to, indeed would be nice to know the magic behind this