# how to download a .zip file after it has been compressed in php

Tags: php, download, zip

I compressed a folder with with a function and the file (compressed.zip) has all the content of the folder. I tested it to download and everything works fine.
Now i want to automatically download the file after compression has done.

This is the code i use for that:

```
if(isset($_GET['compress'])) {
            // compress folder and sent compressed zip to plugins/sfm/views
            Zip($_GET['compress'], "plugins/sfm/views/compressed.zip");

            if(file_exists('plugins/sfm/views/compressed.zip')){
            // set example variables
            $filename = "compressed.zip";
            $filepath = "plugins/sfm/views/";

            // http headers for zip downloads
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Cache-Control: public");
            header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
            header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
            ob_end_flush();
            @readfile($filepath.$filename);
            }


        }
```

Like i said; when i go to plugins/sfm/views/compressed.zip via the url he extracts the folder without problem and all the content is inside it with extraction.
But the forced download gives me a compressed.zip that seems to be corrupted.

When trying to open the download with Winrar, he says: Unexpected end of archive. and: the archive is either in unknown format or damaged.
Why the forced download gives me this error? The zip file is  compressed correctly!

Comment: Compare downloaded file with the one you force-downloaded.

Comment: i confirm, the file is corrupt. But why the forced download delivers a corrupt file to the browser? The original file is intact

Comment: I think that problem could like within spaces or buffer caching - check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311790/php-readfile-causing-corrupt-file-downloads - compare your files to check diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to solve the problem:

```
//clean all levels of output buffering
while (ob_get_level()) {
ob_end_clean();
}
```

before the `@readfile($filepath.$filename);`

Comment: exactly what I suggested ;)