# php readfile bad charset

Tags: php, character-encoding, readfile

I have a php code for downloading file based on file_id from URL. All works great, but I have problems with downloading files with extension .doc

Here is my code, what im doing wrong?

$file = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".sqlprefix."files WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."'"));
    $tmp = explode(".",$file['url']);
    $tmp = $tmp[count($tmp)-1]; 
    // $tmp = "doc";

```
switch ($tmp) {
    case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
    case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
    case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
    case "docx": $ctype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"; break;
    case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
    case "csv":
    case "xls":
    case "xlsx": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
    case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
    case "tif":
    case "tiff": $ctype="image/tiff"; break;
    case "psd": $ctype="image/psd"; break;
    case "bmp": $ctype="image/bmp"; break;
    case "ico": $ctype="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"; break;
    default: $ctype="application/force-download";
}

$baseName = basename($file['url_del']);
$fileSize = filesize($file['url_del']);
$url = $file['url_del'];

// $ctype = "application/msword";
// $baseName = "File name with spaces and diacritic ěščěšč.doc"
// $fileSize = "214016"
// $url = "./files/File name with spaces and diacritic ěščěšč.doc";


    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: '.$ctype);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$baseName);
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: '.$fileSize);
    readfile($url);
    exit;
```

After downloading file in word I get this.

[image]

I think, that problem must be in encoding... enter image description here

Answer (score 3):

It was terrible for me too.
I have found the slution here: [PHP readfile() causing corrupt file downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311790/php-readfile-causing-corrupt-file-downloads)

Try to put this lines before readfile():

```
//clean all levels of output buffering
while (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Comment: I encountered a similar situation and this solved it for me. Thanks!