# Downloaded xml file contain page html

Tags: php, xml, download

I am trying to download xml file from the server like this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileName);
header('Content-type: text/xml');

echo $data;
exit;
```

With this, i can download my xml file, however, the file contain some HTML from the page. 
Any idea on how i stop html to be written in the file? 
I have tried changing the header, adding a content-length ... but still nothing :/

Comment: your generation code please

Comment: The problem will be with content of $data. That unwanted HTML is part of $data or you are using some echoes before echo $data.

Comment: The data is xml code returned from an API, I have made a var_dump of $data and it's a clean XML that is displayed.

Comment: @sajushko I don't have echoes before the echo $data (except for those in another file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i waswandering in stack overflow and found this question:

[PHP readfile() causing corrupt file downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311790/php-readfile-causing-corrupt-file-downloads)

The last answer:

```
while (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Worked like a charm to clear the buffer :)