# Why zip file can't be opened after downloaded but fine via manual transfer?

Tags: php, download, zip

I searched and tried a few previous questions/example codes, but couldn't get this to work.

I'm trying to deliver the results to end-users via PHP code. Here is my code.

```
       $varZipFile = $varBaseNameParts[0] . '.' . $varDate . '.zip';
       $varZipDir = $varBaseNameParts[0] . '_' . $varDate;

       $zip = new ZipArchive();
       $zip->open($varZipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
       $zip->addFile('008.csv');
       $zip->addFile('002.csv');
       $zip->close(); // mark line xxx

       header("Content-Type: application/zip");
       header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=$varZipFile");
       header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($varZipFile)); // with or without this line, got the same error 
       header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); // with or without this line, got the same error 
       readfile($varZipFile);
```

I got the .zip file in my browser. However WinZip cannot open it, neither can 7-Zip. WinZip complains that "Error: Central directory not found".

Interestingly, when I manually transfer the file via WinSCP from my server to my Windows machine, I can open the file with either WinZip or 7-Zip. This indicates it works all fine to 'mark line xxx', and problems occurs in the header lines.

TIA!

Comment: One possibility, check you aren't emitting any whitespace or warnings etc. to the output prior to the readfile - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311790/php-readfile-causing-corrupt-file-downloads

Comment: When you ask a question about an error **ALWAYS** include the **error log**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?

Comment: save file, open with text editor to check top and bottom for php errors

Comment: @Pedro Lobito  I added the error things, where/how to see error logs? Thanks

Comment: @TonyXu Just run the script again

Comment: The code works on my linux, i ran the code without this `$varBaseNameParts[0]` and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ouput buffer may not be cleared before you try to serve the download. Try to clean the output buffer before serving the download with the `ob_clean()` function like this:

```
$zip->close(); // mark line xxx
ob_clean();
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Worked!

Comment: Thank you, saved my own life with this just a few weeks ago =D. Please accept the answer at your convenience, if you please.

Comment: Accepted right after comments. Probably it take a while to refresh at your end.

Comment: I believe you just up-voted the answer. You have to click the check mark to accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I see. I need click the check.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working well on my side, debug this `$varBaseNameParts[0]` to see if the value is correct or try the below code.

```
// $name = name of the archive
// $archive_directory = directory to save the archive
// $file_array = list of files
function create_archive($name, $archive_directory, $file_array) {
    $target_file = $archive_directory . '/' . $name . date('m-d-y').date('h-i-sa') . '.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (count($file_array)) {
        if ($zip->open($target_file, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE)) {
            foreach ($file_array as $file) {
                $zip->addFile($file);
            }
            $zip->close();
            chmod($target_file, 0777);
            return $target_file;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function create_download($archive) {
    $file_name = basename($archive);
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($archive));

    readfile($archive);
}

// create the archive file
$archive = create_archive('test', 'archive', ['008.csv', '002.csv']);
if ($archive) {
    create_download($archive);
}
```

Comment: I used a constant as the zip file name. Still got the same error. I'll try your code now. Thanks

Comment: I tried your code and got error "does not appear to be a valid archive", which I saw it in the course of exploring why I got current error of "central directory not found".

Comment: make sure the `$archive_directory` exists, create it before you pass it.